# How do I make yeoman reload bla.html instead of index.html

Tags: yeoman

When a change is made to any html file in the root, yeoman fires the reload task, but, yeoman does it only to `http://localhost:3501/index.html`. 
How do I let yeoman know that I wanna reload `http://localhost:3501/bla.html` ?

Maybe some Gruntgile.js configurations?

Comment: Works for me out of the box, what version are you using?

Comment: v0.9.6  Im on windows so I have no other option.

Comment: v1 works fine on windows, and it supports this kind of reload.

Comment: U got yeoman 1 running on Windows? Why so quiet man? Put the instructions so I can mark it as an answer. Chocolatey only gives me Yeoman 0.9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeoman 1.0 does this with no problems, it's pretty easy to install. Here is a quick guide:

1. Make sure that you have Node installed with NPM
2. Uninstall the old version of Grunt
3. Install the requirements with NPM like this: `npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower`
4. You now have everything you need, you can run `yo` to confirm that you have the correct version installed.

There is a lot less dependencies, they are moved to a per-project-basic.

You can read a lot more on their website here http://yeoman.io
[Make sure that you read the migration guide.](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Migrate-from-0.9.6-to-1.0)

Note: Their wiki says that it does not work on Windows, this is not the case anymore, I run Windows 7 and it works like charm.

Comment: Can you get - 'grunt server' to run ok on windows 7? I get message saying I need ruby and compass.

Comment: Yes, runs with no problem on my Win7 Machine.

Comment: Does yo angular work for you on win7? It doesn't create components folder for me.

Comment: You have to do this with bower :)